# cant catch code breaking error thrown inside required class

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to scrap a website using pupeteer , this website has captcha and i use a 3rd party library/api to bypass the captcha

here is the simplified version of my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dbc = require('./dpc/deathbycaptcha');

async function init()
{
    let page = launchPuppeteer();
    
    try {

       await page.goto(`https://www.example.com`, {timeout: 60000});
        
        await captcha_element.screenshot({  path: setting.captcha  , omitBackground: true, });
        let captchaResult = await solve_captcha().catch((error)=>  {throw new Error( error) });

       
        log('ALL DONE');
    }
    catch (e) {

        log('=====================ERROR============================');
        log(e);
    }


}
```

here is `solve_captcha` function

```
function solve_captcha(){
    return  new Promise(( resolve , reject )=>{
        try
        {
            const client = new dbc.HttpClient('myUsername',  'myPassword');
            client.decode({captcha: setting.captcha}, (captcha) => {

                if (captcha) {
                    resolve(captcha['text']);
                }
                else
                {
                    reject('error')
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject(e.toString());
        }
    })
}
```

so sometimes i cant connect to captcha solving api due to down server or network problems , it would throw this error

```
C:\pathToProject\dpc\deathbycaptcha.js:218
        throw new Error(err.message);
        ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\pathToProject\dpc\deathbycaptcha.js:218:15)
←[90m    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
←[90m    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)←[39m
←[90m    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)←[39m
←[90m    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)←[39m
←[90m    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
```

this error happens in the `deathbycaptcha.js` which i've required in my code with

```
const dbc = require('./dpc/deathbycaptcha');
```

here is the simplified version of the code in the in the `deathbycaptcha.js` which is cuzing the error

```
class HttpClient extends Client {


  _call(arguments here) {

        var options = {someoptions};

        var form = new FormData();


        const request = form.submit(options, (err, response) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.toString())
            throw new Error(err.message);
          }
          
        // more code here
    }
}
```

so here is the problem , i have this code running inside 2 try/catch blocks

first in the  caller function (`init()`) and second one in the `solve_captcha` function but none of them are able to catch this error and it will break all the code and the program will exit and i have to run it again

why cant i catch and handle this error in my code ?

Comment: Trying to bypass a captcha programmatically is decidedly dodgy in many ways. You're sure your name isn't "heretic"?

Comment: How is that `_call` method related to the `decode` call?

Comment: "*`throw new Error(err.message);`*" - well, don't do that in an asynchronous callback like that of `form.submit`. Reject a promise or pass the error to another callback.

Comment: Btw, `.catch((error)=>  {throw new Error( error) });` is rather pointless, as is `try { … } catch (e) { reject(e.toString()); }`. Omit both. Instead, in the `else { reject('error') }` use `reject(new Error('no captcha response'))`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware solving captcha is handled by api so thats not my problem , i just want to make sure thrown errors by api module wont break my code ... im used to write my username like this cuz not everyone lives in the free world if u know what i mean

Comment: @Bergi `decode` is a function in `Client` class which` HttpClient` extends

Comment: @hretic Yes, but that still doesn't show how `decode` calls `_call`. Please post the complete, actual code of both methods (and everything relevant between them). Without more details, I cannot give a more concrete solution than the advice from my second comment.

Comment: @Bergi well i've never worked with js classes but i think `_call` is like the constructor function for the `HttpClient`  class and after creating object of `HttpClient` we use it to call `decode` function (please take a look at the `solve_captcha` function on how this object is created and calls the decode function  ) ... i dont think they are related at all ... you can check the code here `https://jsfiddle.net/duq15r37/`